# What does "舐め取られてる" mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

> 何者かによってチョコが舐め取られてる

Found it here where people talked about the pocky snack.http://ogiri.doorblog.jp/

Is this "舐め取られてる" just another way of saying 舐める as in "to underestimate"?
Does it mean lick or taste here because of the subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「舐め取る」just means “to lick off”, similar to「舐めて取る」or ”take (something) off by licking”.

In the form of「舐め取られて（い）る」it can either mean that ”something is being licked off” or alternatively that ”something has (already) been licked off”. Based on the context, in this case, it clearly denotes the latter.

This is an ”oogiri”, so people are not actually discussing the snack, but rather trying to come up with fun (ideally, funny) answers to the given subject. In this case, the subject is「こんなポッキーは嫌だ」, i.e. something to the effect of “I would hate this type of pocky” or "This is the last thing I would want to see when I take out a stick of pocky out of the box" etc.

The post in question replies to this subject with “(When you look at the pocky sticks, you notice that) someone has licked off all of the chocolate”.